# How can I improve the clarity of my output animation in Flash CS6?

Tags: cs6, images, animation, adobe-flash, actionscript

I am using Flash CS6 ActionScript 3.0. I am creating an animation with 3-4 images of registration form. The clarity of images is poor in the output of animation even though I am using really clear and large image files.

**What do I need to do to produce clearer animations?**

Comment: Dominic @ I am exporting files in AVI format. and uses PNG or JPG file format of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try right clicking the <kbd>Bitmap > Properties</kbd> and change the `Compression` to `Lossy/Lossless` and try enabling/disabling the `Allow smoothing`.

[image]